# Do I have to recompile .NET application after an Oracle database upgrade

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two applications developed in C# .NET that attacks against an Oracle 11g Database, now the client is planning to upgrade the database to an Oracle 12c.
One of the applications is a windows service and the other is a desktop application.
At this moment I am using `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` **version 2.112.2.0** and it is working properly.
Will my applications keep working properly after the upgrade or should I recompile my applications with another dll?
thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Only you can answer your question as we can't possibly know what functionality your application makes use of in `Oracle.DataAccess`. Perform the upgrade in a separate test environment and perform rigorous testing to be sure.

Comment: Hi, thx for your interest. I only perform some inserts into a table in the database, not more.

Comment: Do your homework then. Look at the differences between versions and whether any breaking changes have been introduced that will affect your application.

Comment: New versions in products like ODP.Net never break the old interfaces, at most it may deprecate, so such testing is not valid, its more about understanding the compatibility of provider with the database

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you don't need to recompile. But just analyzing your code you will be sure of it. So, plan and execute a regression testing of all features on service and desktop application to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand your question little differently and understand what is changing for it, though for the application stack the Oracle Database is upgrading to 12c but for your code the point of contact is the `ODP.Net (Oracle.DataAccess.dll)`, where you are using the certain `version-2.112.2.0`, now the recompilation of depends on the fact whether the current ODP.Net version works with Oracle 12c, if it doesn't, then you need to get the newer compatible version and that means recompilation, but even in that case you can avoid it, by adding a newer ODP.Net binary to the GAC and using the [Binding Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) in the config file, which means that even when it was compiled with an older version at runtime it loads newer version, which means no runtime exception, this is done with many production systems, when newer dependant binary is introduced, since interfaces seldom change, in case you want to use any new API, then surely you need to recompile and redeploy.
Also check the link - [Enabling automatic binding redirects manually](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Following will be app.config setting:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess"
          publicKeyToken="-- ODP.Net Public Token --"
          culture="en-us" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.2.0" newVersion="-- New Version --" />
      </dependentAssembly>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what features were deprecated in version 12 which you may have used. It is one version and companies like Oracle work hard to make new releases backwards compatible. Or, it is possible that the new version have bugs which your code triggers, but that isnt likely. I would expect to test and the tests to pass and not have to invest much time beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should work in the same way. In very rare cases you may use functions in Oracle 11g which have been removed from Oracle 12c. Even in such case you most likely have to modify your actual code rather than upgrade to new ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) version.

Check this document for removed features: [Deprecated and Desupported Features for Oracle Database 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60000)